# How to get child objects of record using table join on Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-17

By example, have a `roles` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.roles (
  id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  role_parent_id bigint NULL DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES public.roles(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  name varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

In the entity `DAO` have this code:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class RoleDAO {
  // ...

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="role_parent_id")
  private RoleDAO parentRole;
```

When need list all roles in a rest controller the example expected is show each root and child roles:

```json
[
    { id: 1, name: "Role 1", roles: [ ] },
    { id: 2, name: "Role 2", roles: [
        { id: 3, name "Role 3", roles: [ ] }
    ] }
]
```

But when call `findAll` method of the `JpaRepository` return all roles with the parent, instead of that i need the child of each role. How to create `childRoles` array into `RoleDAO` entity?